# ¿Donde colocar los Data Annotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Por las dudas que haya problema de conceptos defino:

Model := La clase que establece las Tablas de la base de datos.

ViewModel := La clase que utilizo para enviar a las Vistas (para no pasar el Model completo).

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Para establecer las KEY o indicar que se trata de un valor único posible en la base de datos, tengo que poner los Data Annotations correspondientes en el Model.

Pero para establecer que una propiedad es obligatoria o que no puede ser igual a 0 por ejemplo, ¿pongo los Data Annotation correspondientes en el ViewModel solamente? ¿o tengo que poner tanto en el Model como en el ViewModel?

Se supone que en la Vista se cargan los datos en el ViewModel, por lo tanto es en el ViewModel donde tendría que estar los Data Annotation con sus respectivos mensajes de Error.

¿Estoy en lo cierto?

Answer (score 2):

Los `Data Annotations` debes definirlos en las propiedades que formen parte del binding de controles que quieras validar, si estas bindeando el Model a textbox y quieres indicar que son obligatorios deberas poner el [Required] para indicarlo

Ahora bien, lo que noto es que confundes los atributos de `entity framework` con los que usas en la validacion, cuando defines [Key] esto no es `Data Annotations` pero de `entity framework`, el problema es que usas la misma clase en la `view` y en la `persistencia`, no digo que este mal se que ahora mucho codigo, pero lo aconsejable es que sean clases diferentes

Si tienes una clase `Persona` que usaras con `entity framework` y otra clase `PersonaModel` que usaras con `mvvm` para representar el dato en la view, de esta forma si usas atributos los de persistencia estaran separados a los de visualizacion, la idea es convertir de uno a otro, puedes usar linq o la libreria automapper para ayudarte